# How to calculate determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How to calculate the following determinant:

$\begin{vmatrix}
 a & b & b & ... & b \\ 
 b & a & b &  ... & b \\ 
 . & . & . & . ... & .\\
 b & b & b & ... & a\\
 \end{vmatrix}$

I don't have idea from where to start. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can calculate it with eigenvalues and their multiplicities. Think about the eigenvalues of the matrix $J$ with all $1$s. Then this matrix is just $bJ + (a - b)I$, which is a polynomial of $J$.

Comment: You can try using elementary row operations to diagonalize the matrix since the determinant of a diagonal matrix is just the product of the diagonal entries. But remember, elementary row operations may change the determinant, so keep track of the operations you used.